# Inserting one key's value in another key's value in .json file

Tags: javascript, json

This is my json file

```
{
    "foo": "https://3a1821d0.ngrok.io/api/foo",
    "bar": "https://3a1821d0.ngrok.io/api/bar",
}
```

I want to replace `3a1821d0` with another key in the json file like

```
{
    "some_variable": 3a1821d0,
},
{
    "foo": "https://some_variable.ngrok.io/api/foo",
    "bar": "https://some_variable.ngrok.io/api/bar",
}
```

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Yep, just perform a `replace()` on those strings with the proper regex expression and replacement value

Comment: Your second JSON block is not valid.

Comment: `[Object.entries(data).reduce((a, v) => (a[v[0]]=v[1].replace('3a1821d0', 'some_variable'), a), {}), { some_variable: '3a1821d0' }]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below method to replace the a matched content with desired content. Replace `test` with your desired text.

```js
let data ={
    "foo": "https://3a1821d0.ngrok.io/api/foo",
    "bar": "https://3a1821d0.ngrok.io/api/bar",
}

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => data[key] = data[key].replace(/3a1821d0/,"test"))
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to do this in a .json file and I suppose you're talking about the .js file. Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking to replace in `json` file itself then you might have to write the condition at each value level like `{
    "foo": "https://3a1821d0.ngrok.io/api/foo".replace(/3a1821d0/,"test"),
    "bar": "https://3a1821d0.ngrok.io/api/bar".replace(/3a1821d0/,"test"),
}`. Otherwise, if there's any scope of accessing this `json` in `js` file I would suggest to do that way.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend wrapping the ocurrences you want to replace with `<>` or any other character so that the replacement doesn't collide with the appearance. Called your file `input.json` and this would be its content:

```
{
    "some_variable": "3a1821d0",
    "foo": "https://<some_variable>.ngrok.io/api/foo",
    "bar": "https://<some_variable>.ngrok.io/api/bar"
}
```

Assuming you are using node. This code should do the job.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

let fileContent = fs.readFileSync('input.json', "utf-8");

let content = JSON.parse(fileContent);
const someVariable = content.some_variable;

// I'm adding null and 4 to keep the file beautified
let fileContentStr = JSON.stringify(content, null, 4);

// This line replaces all ocurrences of <some_variable> by "some_variable" content
fileContentStr = fileContentStr.split('<some_variable>').join(someVariable);

// Write file again
fs.writeFileSync('output.json', fileContentStr);
```

Comment: You don't have to read the `json` file using `fs` it'll be a overkill, instead you can directly require in a `js` file and use it as it is.